# Can i use bare hands to jump start motherboard

Tags: motherboard

I have a new PC built but don't have a case presently. I am jumpstarting it. It works with a screwdriver, keys, pens. Previously I was afraid but now I casually do it since touching other metal contacts or if incorrect pins are touched doesn't cause any issue.

Can I also jump-start using my fingers? Without any serious shock etc.

Comment: Are you fingers conductive?

Comment: Yes, they are, you can hold two wires in hand and can have a bulb lit up. Also when I jumpstart just having a little brush up on contacts it's instantaneous so it looks like there is no serious current being passed and just a circuit completion is needed.

Comment: This probably won't work (unless you have conductive metal on your hands). Its not a electrocution risk, but its not safe for the motherboard.  While your hands may he conductive they will have fairly high resistance.

Comment: Also note you are not atrptong to jump start it - you are not providing electricity or using jumper cables. You are trying to short two pins to initiate a startup sequence.

Comment: I think questions here is more theoretical,  if the voltage diff between 2 pins is just 3V what harm there would be, and even with high resistance, I could complete the circuit.

Comment: Because it is just 3 volts (or probably 5) the current is low enough to not have enough resistance to flow through the finger with enough residual electricity to form a loop. It is likely not going to work and the voltage change may cause more voltage to build up causing a sudden spike which may prove to be harmful for the system.

Answer (score 6):

Don't, you might ruin your motherboard.

If you are carrying electrostatic charge (like a capacitator), you might discharge via some electronic components, and fry them. That's why people take "ESD" (Electrostatic Discharge) precautions when handling electronic components... it's not for the operators' safety.